# A probability problem involving two decks of cards

Tags: probability

Here is the problem:

> Player A chooses 5 cards from a deck of cards. Player B also chooses 5 cards from ANOTHER deck of cards. Player B wins if his cards match at least 3 cards of player A. What is the probability that the number of cards of player B matches that of player A's is
>
> ```
> A) 0
> B) 1
> C) 2
> D) 3
> E) 4
> F) 5
> ```

I attempted to solve A) this way:
((52C5)* (47C5)) / ((52C5)*(52C5)) = 0.5902 but I'm not sure if this is right.

Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: Your solution for A is correct

Comment: Please use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference), HTML, bold font, italics, et cetera to format your posts. You should find the markdown `$\binom{A}{B}$` $\binom{A}{B}$ especially relevant.

Answer (score 3):

Assuming that both players are using standard $52$-card decks, the probability that the set of cards $B$ draws has exactly $k$ cards in common with the set of cards $A$ draws is
$$ \frac{{5\choose k}{47\choose 5-k}}{{52\choose 5}}$$
for $k=0,1,2,\dots,5$.

One way to see this is to number $B$'s cards $1$ to $52$, with cards $1$ to $5$ being the cards $A$ has drawn from his deck.

Answer (score 1):

You solved part A) correctly!

For part B), we have $52\choose1$ ways of picking the card that $A$ and $B$ have in common, then $51\choose4$ ways of picking $A$'s other four cards, then $47\choose4$ ways of picking $B$'s other four cards (which have to be completely different from $A$'s). Thus, for part B), the probability is:

$$\frac{{52\choose1}\cdot{51\choose4}\cdot{47\choose4}}{{52\choose5}^2}$$

The rest of the parts proceed similarly.

The numerical results are:

A) $59.021\%$

B) $34.314\%$

C) $6.239\%$

D) $0.416\%$

E) $0.009\%$

F) $0.000038\%$

Comment: Can whoever downvoted please explain?